# How do I know which <li> element was clicked from a <ul>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have an `<ul>`, and every `<li>` has a background 50px*50px but I want to know which `<li>` I click from the ul, the first, second, third.

Each `<li>` has an image, so, when I click a `<li>` the image displays in another `<div>`, but when I want to change the image I want to know which li was the one clicked.

```
$("#ul element").on("click", "li", (function() {
    $("#thediv").hide();
    $("#thediv").empty().append('<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>');
    $("#thediv").fadeIn("slow");
    })
);
```

so when i click a li, the image go to the div, but i want to know which index have that li.(1,2,3,4,5, etc).

Comment: You can use `this` to refer to the clicked element.

Comment: I encourage you to read the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/). There you will find: *"When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching selector"* The [jQuery tutorial about event basics](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) might also be helpful. Really, most of your question can be probably answered by just reading the documentation/tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to get the current index in the list

```
$( this ).index();
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` should tell you which "li" was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `.on()`, you can make a call to `$(this)`, which will select the element that corresponds to the parent `.on()` function.

For example:

```
$("li").click(function(){

    $(this).css("background", "blue");

});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsJ3c/2/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery passes the actual target element of any event via `e.target`, so you could do:

```
$("#ul element").on("click", "li", function(e){
  var $target = $(e.target);
  var index = $target.index();

  ...
  // Assuming you do things with the target here.
});
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/472VT/

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to obtain an index is to simply assign id values to the li, like this:

```
<ul id="indexedList">
<li id="1">1st Index</li>
<li id="2">2nd Index</li>
<li id="3">3rd Index</li>
</ul>
```

Then simply obtain the id by calling the attr() function:

```
$("li").click(function(){

    alert($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YWP2p/1/

Comment: You shouldn't give `id`s to elements unless they _really_ need them. Lots of elements with IDs just gives more information for the browser to keep track of that doesn't really serve a purpose. Also what if your list has 100 items? That's a lot of IDs to make sure you keep in the correct order.